# Protractor is executing onPrepare multiple times in multicapability mode

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am newbie to protractor and javascript. I am trying to execute several tests in parallel using multiCapabilities. However when I do this onPrepare or beforeAll are all executing once per every spec. Is there a way to execute onPrepare and onComplete only once for all tests?

I am facing this issue in two situations. 1. Different browsers. 2. Same browser with multiple instance i.e., as follows. capabilities : { browserName : 'chrome', shardTestFiles : true, maxInstances : 2 }, In both cases my code under onPrepare is executing twice. I have a requirement to write the test result of each test to a Json file and I am creating new file in onPrepare and it is getting over written when I use maxinstances > 1

Comment: Doing so would defeat the purpose of a `beforeAll()`. What different capabilities are you testing against? Just different browsers?

Comment: I am facing this issue in two situations. 1. Different browsers. 2. Same browser with multiple instance i.e., as follows.                           capabilities : {
  browserName : 'chrome',
  shardTestFiles : true,
  maxInstances : 2
 },
In both cases my code under onPrepare is executing twice. I have a requirement to write the test result of each test to a Json file and I am creating new file in onPrepare and it is getting over written when I use maxinstances > 1. I tried this with onPrepare and beforeAll() and same result

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your protractor test cases with multi capability option, Then the `onPrepare` method will be executed for each set of capability you have mentioned in `multi capabilities` object (i.e) Sharded tests run in a different process.

In you case, you need to create your test report file in `beforeLaunch` method. This method will execute only once before initializing protractor global objects.

Kindly refer https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L404 for additional details on `beforeLaunch` method.